# World's smallest (Exception-based) proof-checking language (in Python). In what way is Coq, Lean, Isabelle "better"?

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, computer-science, math-software, proof-theory

As you may already know, the codebases written for Coq, Lean, etc. are humungous.  Thus a goal in a new proof assistant might be to simplify things.  Suppose we restrict our attention not to general proof theory but to categorical contexts.   The closest concept I can think of would be a "CAS for category theory (with proofs)".

```
C = Cat('C')
X = C.ob('X')
i = Id(X, 'i')
j = Id(X, 'j')

with Proof(goal=Eq(i,j), given=[C, X, i, j]) as p:
    eq1 = p.equals(i, j(i))
    eq2 = p.equals(j(i), j)
    p.QED(p.transitivity(eq1, eq2))
    
print(p.proposition_text())
print(p.proof_text())
```

The idea is that `print` will present precisely the following text to the user:

> **Prop.** Let $C$ be a category, $X$ an object in $C$, and $i,j$ identity
> morphisms on $X$.  Then $i = j$.
> **Proof.**
> $$i = i\circ j \tag{1}$$
> $$i\circ j = j \tag{2}$$
> Therefore, $i = j$ by transitivity of equality and (1), (2)  $\blacksquare$

Thus the most basic proof in Category can be given in English using classes `Ob, Cat, Arrow, Id, Proof, and Eq`.    The methods of the proof instance `p` encode how to work with and return equalities.

Thus a proof of a statement is valid if and only if we can construct the statement's goal data.

**Questions.**  Would you consider using such a python library as a student of category theory?  How would Coq, Lean, or Isabelle be superior on this particular proof?  The last question is so that I can make changes to the design, so that it is on par with the other proof assistants.

---

How does proof checking work?  Each method call on the `p` object will perform a run-time `assert` of the proposed equality against the given equalities.  Inclusion of `i,j` into the givens automatically includes their definitional equalities.  Should any assertion fail, the mathematician (or coder / you) will be informed in their IDE of the AssertionFailure.  So that is the proof-checking  mechanism - it makes use of the exception system within a programming language, which is in this case Python's.

If the `with` block is exited without a successful call to `p.QED` then a ProofError will be thrown (another exception).  The data of the argument to QED must equal `p.goal`.

Simply doing `p.equals(i,j)` from the start will result in a ProofError, since the reference `i` does not equal the reference `j`.  That is to say, a real proof environment is indeed formed - a.k.a. you can't cheat on a proof.

Comment: Part of the problem with your proposal is that everything happens at *runtime* rather than at compile time or typechecking time. The great benefit of something like Agda or Lean is that it's actually not a huge amount of work to check a proof, and there's lots of type theory already written about the foundations of proof assistants.

Comment: @PatrickStevens not everything has to be coded the same to reach the same end goal, and as observed, focusing attention on such an area as basic Category Theory, will result in "getting there" to the proofs a lot simpler (to implement) and thus quicker.  Think of this as the informal idea of "relative type theory."  Text books don't prove something all the way down to the most atomic logical objects, they work relative to the lemmas underneath them.  That is to say

Comment: @PatrickStevens That is to say we work relative to the (most basic) concepts such as compositions of maps (which is encoded in the classes).  In this relative way, we choose a topic area of math (much like writing a textbook) and work relative to everything else.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Python's compilation is the same stage as running.  Unless it's precompiled to bytecode or turned into an EXE for each system.  So think of an exception as either compile time (or equivalently run time).

Comment: I'm aware. But Python's intensely dynamic nature is exactly what makes Python tooling so much worse than tooling for a statically-typed language. You propose making proofs similarly dynamic, and as far as I can tell, the only result will be that the tooling for your system will be necessarily as limited as Python's.

Comment: Can you use your system to prove the adjoint functor theorem?

Comment: For example, I think you'll find it relatively *very* difficult to infer proof terms automatically. Agda and Idris have a kind of magical ability to do this, and they can do it in a local way. You are going to have to run the entire program.

Comment: @PatrickStevens in any programming language you only actually run the used portions.  If compiled to bytecode, surely not every piece of code is executed until it finally *is executed*.  I argue that Python is just as good of a language to implement dependent types in.  Granted they don't mesh in with regular types and `=` means `:` in type theory, but this is the way (and I've experimented with many syntax mechanisms for this) that I've found most elegant for implementation.  There are some dependent statically typed libraries for Python though.  This is much nicer as a Python developer.

Comment: @PatrickStevens an interpreter for the language would load the library code only once, and you can easily execute user-entered python snippets in Python using `exec` which is what makes Python nice (no need to write another parser / another host language for the app).

Comment: Well, for one, your language has mutable state. You *can't* check anything for validity without first evaluating all the preceding program. Agda can do it entirely by looking at locally-available information.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, surely evaluating a program in Agda means calling some library functions / testing return value.  Why separate compile-time running from actual run-time execution.  It makes no difference in this scenario.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Not everything gets evaluated, only the parts of code called in the "proof tree".  It's just like any other language...

Comment: You can type-check a program in Agda without evaluating anything (beyond that which is absolutely necessary to evaluate, e.g. when you are proving that `f 1 = f 0` by pattern-matching on both sides). The construction of proof terms is (modulo tactics) totally static, and I can type-check a proof of two independent things in the same file independently. Python can't do that in general, because the dynamically-constructed proof terms may mutate global state and may therefore have interrelated proofs.

Comment: @PatrickStevens pattern-matching involves a lot of code.  Whether this code is part of the library or a separate entity called a compiler is an independent idea of what is presented above.  I don't state that I'm trying to promote the features of the host language in how the code is run or type-checked.

Comment: @PatrickSteven Python is indeed able to run multiple threads of proof-checking.  That's a minor detail here.  The above is more related to UX or user experience.

Comment: @PatrickStevens we ultimately trust how the Coq kernel is coded and that it does what the feature list describes.  I'm asking nothing different than this, and I assert we can analogously trust something coded in Python.

Comment: By the way, Lean, Coq, Agda, and Isabelle are nowhere near minimal as far as proof checkers are concerned. One system that really takes proof verifier parsimony seriously is [Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/index.html), which has a [python verifier](http://us.metamath.org/downloads/mmverify.py) of only 350 lines (among over a dozen alternate verifiers in most major programming languages).

Comment: You're all right, upon second consideration.  If I were to do the above, it would best be done in an already math-rich language such as Haskell, or alternatively I should just learn Coq or Lean coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thing would be *possible*. I really struggle to believe it would be remotely as ergonomic as e.g. Lean, though. Phrasing your proofs as types in a strong type system gives the compiler perfect knowledge, and allows it to be extremely helpful (if you haven't experienced Agda or Idris's hole-filling, it is actually miraculous). The extremely dynamic nature of Python means you are crippled from the start. If the user promises they will stick only to using your built-ins, then sure, you could get an experience like Lean's or Coq's where the interactive proof assistant tells you all the information available, but you're embedded in Python where anything goes, so it's quite a bit of trust you're putting on the user.

Additionally, Python is based around mutable state. Your proof terms are inherently dynamic, and the fact that your language is running inside Python means you are inviting the user to knit together proof terms using mutability. I do not believe this will lead to readable or maintainable proofs, and it also makes the job of the kernel a lot harder: if I construct a proof term in function `f`, then I use it in proof `h`, then I mutate it in function `g`, you're going to have to *track* this somehow so that you can re-evaluate the construction of `h`. This sounds like a pretty big undertaking to me, not that I'm deeply familiar with Python's reflection APIs. An immutable language rules out this entire can of worms.

Comment: I assert we can trust the users of such a system.  After all, don't we trust peer-reviewing?  And proof terms are not mutable.  If you hide something by _privateMember (underscore-started), then that member is effectively private (not visible to the Python environment except where Python introspects).  Introspectiion is a good thing though.  So if there is no write method, then those members are read only.  Of course another user can come into the fold and code something that is provably False, but so can you in Coq I argue.  Coq is also a powerful programming language, so surely this is true.

Comment: Addressing your data structure question involving $f, h, g$.  Doing `f(g)` will return a `Comp(f,g)` object which is a  composition of arrows, and upon construction checks that the codomain of $g$ equals the domain of $f$.  This is all verifiable by the user community because that checking code is a simple assert statement.  Their IDE will take them to the failure.  A `Comp` object is a subclass of `Arrow` (morphism) where Python acts like C++ or any other OOP language inheritance-wise.  It's only when the data structures are asked to convert to string do things flatten out into strings.

Comment: In other words, Python handles immutability by the way the users will be standardized to code things that get added to the standard library.  That's okay with me.  A computer can be coded to return anything.  It's always a matter of what someone typed in and some point in time.  So you can never 100% rule out human error anyway.

Comment: "I assert we can trust the users of such a system.  After all, don't we trust peer-reviewing?" If the entire code and the users (proof writers) need to be trusted, then what is the value added by the proof assistant? The whole point of formal verification is that the computer checks the proof so that you don't have to, and if the user can circumvent the library restrictions then not only the library but each step of the proof has to be vetted. Python's ability to add introspection and hooks to everything makes it trivial to fool the "trusted kernel".

Comment: "Of course another user can come into the fold and code something that is provably False, but so can you in Coq I argue." - that does happen sometimes, and it's treated as a major bug every time. Mario will know much better than me, but I think nobody's ever proved False in Lean?

Comment: There was a recent soundness bug in the lean 4 alpha that was quickly fixed but otherwise it's had a completely clean slate since lean 0.1.